# ffmpeg colorspace conversion speed

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, color-space

I am running 2 ffmpeg commands on a fairly fast, GPU-enabled machine (AWS g2.2xlarge instance):

```
ffmpeg -i ./in.mp4 -s 1280x720 -r 30 -an -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p - | cat - >/dev/null
```

gives 524fps while

```
ffmpeg -i ./in.mp4 -s 1280x720 -r 30 -an -f rawvideo -pix_fmt argb - | cat - >/dev/null
```

just 101... it just shouldn't, couldn't take as much as 8ms per frame on a modern CPU, let alone GPU!

What am i doing wrong and how can i improve speed of this?

PS: Now this is truly ridiculous!

```
ffmpeg -i ./in.mp4 -s 1280x720 -r 30 -an -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p - | ffmpeg -s 1280x720 -r 30 -an -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -i - -s 1280x720 -r 30 -an -f rawvideo -pix_fmt argb - | cat - >/dev/null
```

makes 275 fps! which is by far not perfect, but something i can live with.

why?

Thanks!

Comment: Notice the bitrate is almost the same, ~4.0225Mbits/s, so they're likely running on the same device. I don't know how to make it faster, but it's definitely already running on the GPU.

Comment: the colorspace conversion? why do you think it runs on the GPU? the bitrate refers to the bitrate of output mp4, it is same because i force it to be same with -b:v. of course its encoding runs on GPU, and i don't have a problem with its speed. i have a problem with the speed of colorspace conversion. to me, it seems very slow, 340mbytes of raw data per second... on a multi core machine with SIMD instructions... that doesn't sound fast to me.

Comment: Oh, then nevermind. I apologize for the mistake, I misunderstood the debug output. I've only ever used ffmpeg for converting sound files, I always thought the bitrate referred to the conversion speed for some reason.

Comment: `libswscale` that typically performs colorspace conversion in `ffmpeg` does not use GPU acceleration, does not use parallel computations and it does not even use any modern CPU instruction sets, such as `AVX`, for YCbCr to RGB conversion. Also conversion lacks precision. I can not say that `libswscale` is abandoned, but its development is definitely falling behind.

Answer (score 2):

*it is easy to see that GPU is used for output encoding - no CPU could encode mp4 at 1280x720x30fps at 10x the playback speed*

Are you sure? On a mid-range Haswell i5, my CPU encodes get around 4-5x for that resolution. Since you haven't specified a codec, ffmpeg will default to libx264 for MP4 output, which does NOT encode on a GPU.

Check the output of your ARGB pipeline. In order to save as RGB, libx264 has to be called explicitly as `-c:v libx264rgb`. Except H.264 does not store alpha. So for MP4 format, you'll probably have to encode as VP9, using a very recent build of ffmpeg. The output will be a YUV pixel format with an alpha plane. If MOV works, PNG and QTRLE are your other options.

I'm not aware of a hardware-accelerated encoder for VP9/PNG/QTRLE usable with ffmpeg.

Comment: Great! OK can you suggest me which codec to specify to make sure it encodes on a GPU? I will see how it impacts encoding speed while using yuv420p.

Comment: `h264_nvenc`, `h264_qsv`

Comment: Thanks. By the way, i just tried on a machine with no GPU (Packet.net type 0) and it is almost equally slow in both cases... 0.486x for yuv420p and 0.34x for argb. So speed drop on a fast processor is much much more pronounced.

Comment: `No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb`